# removeEventListener on class name after one click

Tags: javascript, dom-events, addeventlistener, removeeventlistener

I'm trying to write some Javascript to get click event on all elements with class from an array. Everything works fine, but I need it unclickable only until second condition in `klikej()` function is met. Once the click event fires, then the item with that class shouldn't be clickable. I've tried using `removeEventListener` and/or handle it with `PreventDefaults()`, but nothing works. I need to use only vanilla Javascript - no jQuery or anything else. Could you please help me?

```
    poleRandomKaret.forEach(karta => {
    document.querySelectorAll(`.${karta}`).forEach(element => {
        element.addEventListener('click', event => {
            console.log("klik");
            klikej(event, element);
        });
    });
});


function klikej(event, element) {
    let kliknuteKarty = document.querySelectorAll('[data-ovoce]');
    if (kliknuteKarty.length < 2) {
        element.setAttribute('data-ovoce', 'otoceno');
    }
    kliknuteKarty = document.querySelectorAll('[data-ovoce]');
    if (kliknuteKarty.length === 2) {
        kliknuteKarty[0].className === kliknuteKarty[1].className ? console.log("yes") : console.log("nope");
        kliknuteKarty.forEach(element => {
            element.removeAttribute("data-ovoce");
        });
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** The item shouldn't be clickable until the second condition in `klikej()` function is met. I'm trying to do memory game using vanilla JS. Function `klikej()` sets data attribute to an item and once there are two items with identical data attributes, it'll print in console "yes". If they're two different data attributes, they needs to be clickable again.

Comment: Is the handler you're trying to remove an anonymous one? If the handler doesn't have a name, you can't identify it later  -like when you want to remove it.

Comment: It is. So, what should I do? Should I transform it into function?

Comment: Re: your edit. If you want the callabck to either fire or not depending on the true/false state of something else somewhere in your JS or even an attribute in the DOM... and this state can turn on and off at different intervals. You don't want to remove the event listener, you just want to wrap your callback logic in an if statement that checks the value of the thing your testing against.

Comment: You should post your HTML as well so we can work up an example solution.

Comment: I think you should edit this line ```but I need it working only once.``` This is misleading I think.

Comment: @JanRadosta = it already is a function. You've declared it without a name in the very place that the name would go if not for the fact its anonymous. So, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you remove event listener, and will need to listen again, you would need to add it again or listen with something else. If I would need to recognize if something was clicked, I would add property to the element in the listener callback, so something like:

```
// before anything else we check if it was clicked before
if (element.clicked) {
    // do your magic when element was already clicked
} else {
    // do different magic with not yet opened element here
}
// after you did everything needed
// set the clicked attribute to true or false (if you need "unclick" it)
element.clicked = true;
```

It isn't directly answer to your question but hopefully another view to possible solution - if I understood you correctly, you do something when it was clicked and something else when it wasn't yet clicked and here you have control for both cases.

Answer (score 1):

You can add an option called `once` as the third parameter of the [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener), which makes the event listener execute once.

```
element.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    console.log('clicked'); // This will be executed once.
}, {once: true});
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the response. I've tried that, but that would mean, that the item will not be clickable anymore. I need it to be clickable just until my condition in klikej() will be met. Then it needs to reset. I'll edit the post.